# Have MySQL not delete leading 0 from a value

Tags: php, mysql, forms, apache

I am trying to store phone numbers of users in my database, but MySQL automatically deletes the first 0, the information is coming from a html form.

for example: when someone enters a phone number `0123456789`, mysql stores the value `123456789`.

Does anyone know how to make this work and include the `0` in the database?

Comment: remember that phone numbers are not "numbers", they are letters.

Comment: Phone "numbers" aren't actually numbers, they are strings containing digits

Comment: 2=ABC 3=DEF 4=GHI etc. ^ well technically they are, on MY phone anyway ;-)

Comment: You're probably getting an area code of 041 for instance at the beginning of a full telephone number from user input, which I believe is what the Philippines is. This as an example of course.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Store the value as a string. When you store it as a integer the leading zeroes will be removed.

Comment: Oh, big payoff on this one ;-)

Comment: Thanks John! not sure why people are downvoting my question though.. thought it was a legit question..

Comment: a guess would be the downvotes are from people who consider this information that you can find by searching around a bit for "how best to store phone numbers" on the web. It's a legitimate question, but also one that could have been solved without asking on SO =)